In GIMP, corners of the layer never show up for easy scaling
Ever since I've been using GIMP (for a few years now), the scaling option doesn't work the way I'd expect; I always have to scale by pixels or percentage or something similar from the dropdown, and see if the scaled results are the correct size. If not, I Undo, and try again.
I basically never get the option of manipulating via the corners of a layer.
What am I doing wrong? Some obscure setting, perhaps? I feel like it's likely something silly I've overlooked.

You see corner handles if you use the Scale tool.

You can also use the "Unified transform" tool that combines Scale/Rotate/Shear/Perspective in one tool.

The UT is a bit more complex to use, but is to be preferred when one use of the tool replaces several transform tools in succession (matching things in two pictures often s requires scaling and rotation...).
By default the Gimp tool palette only shows the Unified Transform tool, because tools are grouped. If you want to use the Scale tool, you can access it by right-clicking the UT icon (or use the mouse wheel over that icon to scroll the other tools in the group). Another solution is to tell Gimp to not use groups (Edit > Preferences > Interface > Toolbox > Use tool groups).
